# request copied from firebug as cURL request doesn't work

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I am developing a bot application that login into a chat application (et chat) and send messages to users.
The application itself send Ajax requests periodically to retrieve online users and It returns the users list as json object like a charm.
Even when I resend the request in firebug console manually It works good again but when i copy request as cURL in firebug and send it with cURL command engine the request successfully send but i give a database error from server:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 42000
    [1] => 1064
    [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
)
SELECT ekhraj FROM db1_etchat_user where etchat_user_id = 
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in /home/mokhtal/domains/mokhtal.com/public_html/class/ConnectDB.class.php on line 76
```

It is very strange think because I think there is not any difference between this two same request to server so I should not get two different responses.

I don't think providing more information can help to finding the problem but I would be  appreciate if You inform me about the need to more information.

thanks

EDIT: The request and response headers when the request sends normally with browser and receive valid answer are :

```
Response Headers
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0
Connection  close
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Date    Wed, 02 Oct 2013 14:23:53 GMT
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma  no-cache
Server  lighttpd/1.4.28
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.27
Request Headers
Accept  text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Length  18
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie  PHPSESSID=q0guk9lf3d2gb0lgs2ebejhb72; db1_cookie_test=1380723404; cookie_last_login=1380723823; cookie_anzahl_logins_in_XX_sek=1
Host    mokhtal.com
Referer http://mokhtal.com/?Chat
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
X-Prototype-Version 1.7
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

and POST parameter is :

```
reloadsequenz=4000
```

when I use copy as cURL menu in firebug , It returns below code :

```
curl 'http://mokhtal.com/?ReloaderUserOnline' -H 'Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -H 'Cookie: PHPSESSID=q0guk9lf3d2gb0lgs2ebejhb72; db1_cookie_test=1380723404; cookie_last_login=1380723823; cookie_anzahl_logins_in_XX_sek=1' -H 'Host: mokhtal.com' -H 'Referer: http://mokhtal.com/?Chat' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0' -H 'X-Prototype-Version: 1.7' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' --data 'reloadsequenz=4000'
```

Answer (score -1):

To me it seems that cURL has no url to reference to thats why its a non-object

Comment: Can you please  explain  more about that and  how I should solve it?

Comment: can you maybe post the code where you sent the curl request from, right now i only see output so its hard to see where the input error is